# Question on Counting Cards

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**Question:**

> In how many ways can a gambler draw five cards from as standard deck  and get
>
> a)four of a kind
>
> b)three aces and a pair
>
> c)three of a kind and a pair
>
> d)three of a kind
>
> e)two pairs?

---

a)A kind can be selected in $4C1$. $4$ cards can be selected in $13C4$.  And the $5$th card can be selected in $48C1$. Result: $4C1 \cdot 13C4 \cdot 48C1$. What's wrong?

b)Here, $3$ Aces can be selected in $4C3$. I am confused with selecting the pair.

Wanted to know how can we select $3$ of a kind and pairs?

Question Source: Grimaldi, *Discrete Maths*

Comment: As to a): A kind can be selected in $13$ ways.  The four cards can be selected in $1$ way.  The fifth card can be selected in $48$ ways.  $13\cdot48$ ways.

Comment: So kind means the numbers and not the types..Then for c) choosing a kind in 13C1 ways and choosing 3 of a kind in 4C3 ways so what is choosing a pair.

Answer (score 2):

> In how many ways can a gambler draw five cards from a standard deck and get four of a kind?

Four of a kind means that four cards from the same rank are chosen among the five cards.  The rank of the four cards, as saulspatz pointed out in the comments, can be selected in $13$ ways.  There is only one way to choose all four cards of the same rank.  The rank of the remaining card can be chosen in $12$ ways.  The suit of the remaining card can be chosen in four ways.  Hence, the number of ways of selecting four of a kind is 
$$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{4}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{1}$$

> In how many ways can a gambler draw five cards from a standard deck and get three aces and a pair?

As you observed, three aces can be selected in $\binom{4}{3}$ ways.  The pair must be selected from one of the other twelve ranks.  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose two of the four suits of that rank.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$
hands with three aces and a pair.

> In how many ways can a gambler draw five cards from a standard deck and get three of a kind and a pair?

This hand, which is known as a full house, consists of three cards of one rank and two cards of another rank.  There are $13$ ways to choose the rank from which three cards are drawn and $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to choose three cards of that rank.  There are $\binom{12}{1}$ ways to choose the rank of the pair and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to choose two of the four cards of that rank.  Hence, the number of ways of selecting a full house is

> $$\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}$$

---

> In how many ways can a gambler draw five cards from a standard deck and get three of a kind?

This means that three cards of one rank and one card each of two other ranks are chosen.  Choose the rank from which three cards are drawn and three cards of that  rank.  Choose the two ranks from which one card is drawn and one card from each of those ranks.

> In how many ways can a gambler draw five cards from a standard deck and get two pairs?

This means that two cards each are drawn from two ranks and one card is drawn from a different rank.  Choose two ranks from which two cards are drawn and choose two cards from each of those ranks.  Choose a rank from which the other card is drawn and one of the four cards of that rank.

Comment: I was confused with selection of pairs, and you cleared it. Appreciate your help.Thanks